# Number of cycles of length 4 in K7

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

The answer to this I believe is

$1/2$ * $7C3$ * $3!$

How do you arrive to this answer?
I understand the $1/2$ since the graph is undirected, but nothing else. Isn't there 4 ways to choose a cycle of length 4? not 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $7C3=7C4$ it doesn't matter which you use.  I agree that $7C4$ seems better motivated as you choose the four vertices for your cycle, but you could as well choose the three that are not in the cycle.

Now that you have four vertices, how many cycles are there?  I would say there are $4!$ ways to put the vertices in order.  We have counted each cycle $8$ times, four for where we start and two for the direction, so that gives $\frac {4!}{4 \cdot 2}=3=\frac {3!}2$.  I guess you get $\frac {3!}2$ by numbering the vertices and saying you will start the cycle at the lowest number.  Then there are $3!$ ways to order the rest of the vertices and you divide by $2$ for the two ways around.

Comment: So if you fix a vertex, there are 3! ways to order the rest. This relationship right here isn't clear to me. Why are there 3! ways to order 3 vertices with 1 fixed vertex?

Comment: I am fixing the vertex to pick a starting point in the cycle.  Then the other three can come in any order to go around the cycle.  This gives $1234,1243,1324,1342,1423,1432$ as our cycles, but then as you say, each cycle is shown twice, once going each direction.  $1234$ and $1432$ are really the same cycle.